# How would I correctly format a model property that's an enum type in CoreData?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, enums, codable

So I'm trying to access icons from OpenWeather API that has different images for each case 
of weather for example night, day, snow, and etc.

The Weather class is subclassing NSManagedObject and Codable protocol, but the type enum property won't be accepted. It's a little confusing for me.

**What is the way to correctly format this?**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Weather)
public class Weather: NSManagedObject, Codable {

    @NSManaged public var icon: Icon

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case icon
    }

    public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
           guard
               let contextUserInfoKey = CodingUserInfoKey.context,
               let managedObjectContext = decoder.userInfo[contextUserInfoKey] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
               let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Weather", in: managedObjectContext) else {
                   fatalError("Could not retrieve context")
           }

           self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

           let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
           icon = try container.decode(Icon.self, forKey: .icon)
       }

       public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
           var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
           try container.encode(icon.self, forKey: .icon)
       }

}
```

> Here in the same class as Weather, I have the Icon enum.

```
 public enum Icon: Codable {
        // clear sky
        case the01D = "01d"
        case the01N = "01n"

        // few clouds
        case the02D = "02d"
        case the02N = "02n"

        // scattered clouds
        case the03D = "03d"
        case the03N = "03n"

        // broken clouds
        case the04D = "04d"
        case the04N = "04n"

        // shower rain
        case the09D = "09d"
        case the09N = "09n"

        // rain
        case the10D = "10d"
        case the10N = "10n"

        // thunderstorm
        case the11D = "11d"
        case the11N = "11n"

        // snow
        case the13D = "13d"
        case the13N = "13n"

        // mist
        case the50D = "50d"
        case the50N = "50n"
    }
```

Comment: Separate Parsing from the actual model. Create a struct called `WeatherRecord` and make it conform to `Codable`. Then add an initialiser to `Weather` that accepts `WeatherRecord` as a parameter. IMHO it is a better approach so that you can do any business logic validation in `Weather`. As a consequence it would also solve your problem.

Comment: Ok yeah good idea, great way to separate. Thanks